# Remove duplicates based on condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to remove duplicates from my xml based on a condition in XSLT1.0

Here is the input xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
    <Header>
        <MessageId>{D5B72T7A-58E0-4930-9CEB-A06RT56AR21B0}</MessageId>
        <Action>http://tempuri.org/TRH_FinalQueryService/find</Action>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <MessageParts
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
            <TRH_FinalQuery
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/TRH_FinalQuery">
                <TRH_UnionView class="entity">
                    <Company>1</Company>
                    <CS/>
                    <Text_1>1</Text_1>
                    <Text_2>Lotion</Text_2>
                    <WS/>
                </TRH_UnionView>
                <TRH_UnionView class="entity">
                    <Company>1</Company>
                    <CS>1</CS>
                    <Text_1>1</Text_1>
                    <Text_2>Soap</Text_2>
                    <WS>6</WS>
                </TRH_UnionView>
                <TRH_UnionView class="entity">
                    <Company>2</Company>
                    <CS/>
                    <Text_1>5</Text_1>
                    <Text_2>Shampoo</Text_2>
                    <WS/>
                </TRH_UnionView>
                   <TRH_UnionView class="entity">
                    <Company>2</Company>
                    <CS/>
                    <Text_1>5</Text_1>
                    <Text_2>Shampoo</Text_2>
                    <WS/>
                </TRH_UnionView>
                   </TRH_FinalQuery>
        </MessageParts>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Here is the xslt that I have applied.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/TRH_FinalQuery" exclude-result-prefixes="m r">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:key name="r:TRH_FinalQuery" match="r:TRH_FinalQuery" use="concat(r:Text_1, '|', r:Company)" />
  <!-- move all elements to no namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="r:TRH_FinalQuery[r:TRH_UnionView[@class='entity']/r:WessexCostCenter=''][key('r:TRH_FinalQuery',concat(r:Text_1, '|', r:Company))[1]]"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- removes Envelope -->
  <xsl:template match="m:Envelope">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- removes Header,MessageId,Action and Body -->
  <xsl:template match="m:*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- rename MessageParts to Document + skip the Run wrapper -->
  <xsl:template match="m:MessageParts">
    <DocumentElement>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:TRH_FinalQuery/*" />
    </DocumentElement>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- rename RunObject to Item -->
  <xsl:template match="r:TRH_UnionView[@class='entity']">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="r:WS!=''">

        <Item>
          <Text_1>
            <xsl:value-of select="r:WS" />
          </Text_1>
          <Text_2>WS BodayWash</Text_2>
          <Company>
            <xsl:value-of select="r:Text_1" />
          </Company>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Text_1>
            <xsl:value-of select="r:WS" />
          </Text_1>
          <Text_2>WS BodayWash</Text_2>
          <Company>0123</Company>
        </Item>

      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>

        <Item>

          <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Text_1" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Text_2" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Company" />
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Text_1" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Text_2" />
          <Company>0123</Company>
        </Item>

      </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the output I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Item>
    <Text_1>1</Text_1>
    <Text_2>Lotion</Text_2>
    <Company>1</Company>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Text_1>1</Text_1>
    <Text_2>Lotion</Text_2>
    <Company>0123</Company>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Text_1>6</Text_1>
    <Text_2>WS BodayWash</Text_2>
    <Company>1</Company>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Text_1>6</Text_1>
    <Text_2>WS BodayWash</Text_2>
    <Company>0123</Company>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Text_1>5</Text_1>
    <Text_2>Shampoo</Text_2>
    <Company>2</Company>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Text_1>5</Text_1>
    <Text_2>Shampoo</Text_2>
    <Company>0123</Company>
  </Item>
</DocumentElement>
```

Below is the expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Item>
    <Text_1>6</Text_1>
    <Text_2>WS BodayWash</Text_2>
    <Company>1</Company>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Text_1>6</Text_1>
    <Text_2>WS BodayWash</Text_2>
    <Company>0123</Company>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Text_1>5</Text_1>
    <Text_2>Shampoo</Text_2>
    <Company>2</Company>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Text_1>5</Text_1>
    <Text_2>Shampoo</Text_2>
    <Company>0123</Company>
  </Item>
</DocumentElement>
```

I am trying to remove all duplicates based on condition

1. If the Text_1 and Company are same.
2. If the point 1 is true then retain all records having value in WS tag and remove records where there no value in WS tag.

Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/TRH_FinalQuery" 
exclude-result-prefixes="m r">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="myKey" match="r:TRH_UnionView" use="concat(r:Text_1, '|', r:Company)" />

<!-- Simplify things by not having an identity. Using this approach, you will not have to suppress 
     any elements.
-->
<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Start at the root. -->
<xsl:template match="/">
  <DocumentElement>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </DocumentElement>  
</xsl:template>
  
<xsl:template match="r:TRH_UnionView">
  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- Handle the duplicates with no value in the WS tag. -->
    <xsl:when test="count(key('myKey',concat(r:Text_1, '|', r:Company))) &gt; 1 and 
                    count((key('myKey',concat(r:Text_1, '|', r:Company)))[r:WS!='']) = 0">
      <!-- Is this the first of the duplicates?  -->
      <xsl:if test="generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('myKey',concat(r:Text_1, '|', r:Company))[1])">
       <Item>
          <Text_1>
            <xsl:value-of select="r:Text_1"/>
          </Text_1>
          <Text_2>
            <xsl:value-of select="r:Text_2"/>            
          </Text_2>
          <Company>
            <xsl:value-of select="r:Company"/>
          </Company>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Text_1>
            <xsl:value-of select="r:Text_1"/>
          </Text_1>
          <Text_2>
            <xsl:value-of select="r:Text_2"/>            
          </Text_2>
          <Company>0123</Company>
        </Item>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:when>
    <!-- Handle the duplicates with value at least one value in the WS tag. -->
    <xsl:when test="count(key('myKey',concat(r:Text_1, '|', r:Company))) &gt; 1">
      <xsl:if test="r:WS!=''">
        <Item>
          <Text_1>
            <xsl:value-of select="r:WS" />
          </Text_1>
          <Text_2>WS BodayWash</Text_2>
          <Company>
            <xsl:value-of select="r:Text_1" />
          </Company>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Text_1>
            <xsl:value-of select="r:WS" />
          </Text_1>
          <Text_2>WS BodayWash</Text_2>
          <Company>0123</Company>
        </Item>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <Item>
        <Text_1>
          <xsl:value-of select="r:Text_1"/>
        </Text_1>
        <Text_2>
          <xsl:value-of select="r:Text_2"/>            
        </Text_2>
        <Company>
          <xsl:value-of select="r:Company"/>
        </Company>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Text_1>
          <xsl:value-of select="r:Text_1"/>
        </Text_1>
        <Text_2>
          <xsl:value-of select="r:Text_2"/>            
        </Text_2>
        <Company>0123</Company>
      </Item>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Quick note, if you want to use  <xsl:template match=star>, make sure you put it in a mode and add mode to the apply-templates that are targeting the template match= star.

Comment: The xslt you have provided is having issue in one scenario where there are multiple records having the same Text_1 and Company but none of them is having value in WS tag. In this scenario it is deleting all records. I have edited the input xml.

Comment: That's actually what your spec was: If the point 1 is true then retain all records having value in WS tag and remove records where there no value in WS tag.  So, what do you want to happen when there are multiple records having the same Text_1 and Company but none of them having a value in WS tag?  (In your expected output, only one of the duplicates that meet this criteria is being handled.  Which one?)

Comment: I did modify my answer to give you what I think you want.  But, there's enough there to get you going.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to get the expect xml output